# GitLab create branch of a project

Tags: gitlab

We currently have GitLab setup as follows:

B2B\Client (repository), under that we have several different C# projects.  I need to branch one of those projects so that a developer can work on it without impacting the main.  Is there a way to do it?  I can only see creating a branch from the Main, which is what I don't want to do.

```
B2B
    Client (repository)
        Project A
        Project B
        Project C
```

Comment: You can create branches of branches using the git cli

Comment: Not a duplicate, but possibly interesting info for you: [How to split a large Git repository into multiple small independent repos without cloning the large repo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48806538/3124333)